# Order isomorphic implies order preserving if and only if maps are identity maps

Tags: order-theory

Show that the two ordered sets $(P,\leq)$ and $(Q,\leq)$ are order isomorphic if and only if there exist order preserving maps $$X: P\to Q \\
Y: Q \to P$$ such that $X\circ Y = \text{id}_Q$ and $Y\circ X = \text{id}_P$, $\text{id}$ being identify map.

Where and how do we use the identity map ?

Answer (score 0):

If f:X -> Y is an order isomorphism, so is its inverse g:Y -> X.
Clearly f o g and g o f are identities.
Conversely, if f is order preserving and f o g is identity,
then, f is surjective, hence order isomorphism.